# Image_to_string not reading text from tiff or tif files using pytesseract

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

I am trying to read text from tif or tiff image files. These files have multiple pages.

When I print the array i only get true and then no text. However when i use .png files i am able to print the text.

Below is my code.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import numpy as np
import cv2
test = Image.open(r'C:\Python\BG36820V1.tiff')
#test1 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Documents\declaration.png')
testarray = np.array(test)
print(testarray)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(testarray))
```

This is the out put for the test file:

```
[[ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 ...
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]]
```

However this works fine with the test1.

```
[[[242 242 242 255]
  [242 242 242 255]
  [242 242 242 255]
  ...
  [242 242 242 255]
  [242 242 242 255]
  [242 242 242 255]]

 [[182 180 182 255]
  [182 180 182 255]
  [182 180 182 255]
  ...
  [182 180 182 255]
  [182 180 182 255]
  [182 180 182 255]]
g Request 4042337300021 submitted sucessfully

x
TYPE
```

i tried opencv to read tiff files i get format not supported.

How do i get to print the text from the tiff or tif files.

Any suggestions?

Regards,
Ren.

Answer (score 0):

Modified my entire code and converted the tiff files to jpeg file and it was able to read the text.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
yourpath = r'C:\Python\'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[1].lower() == ".tiff":
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"):
                print ("A jpeg file already exists for %s" % name)
            # If a jpeg is *NOT* present, create one from the tiff.
            else:
                outfile = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(root, name))[0] + ".jpg"
                try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(root, name))
                    print ("Generating jpeg for %s" % name)
                    im.thumbnail(im.size)
                    im.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=100)
                except Exception as e:
                    print (e)

test = Image.open(r'C:\Python\BG96254V1.jpeg')

testarray = np.array(test)
print(testarray)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(testarray)))
```

This only reading the 1st page not the list of pages. Any suggestions how to make that change to read all the pages.

Thanks.